# Method lcl_util called only once in a loop why?

Tags: abap

The following program runs fine, however, the SELECT..ENDSELECT part runs only once, whereas it should be calling the class method lcl_util multiple times once for each rows in the table? Why is this due to?

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  ZDYNAMIC_PROG2
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT  ZDYNAMIC_PROG2.
PARAMETER:
 p_from(30) TYPE c DEFAULT 'T001L',
 p_where(255) TYPE c
 DEFAULT 'WERKS = ''PL01'' AND LGORT = ''SL01'' '.
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*        CLASS lcl_util DEFINITION
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*
 CLASS lcl_util DEFINITION.
   PUBLIC SECTION.
     CLASS-METHODS:
     write_struct IMPORTING p_struct TYPE any.
 ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_util DEFINITION
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*        CLASS lcl_util IMPLEMENTATION
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*
* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*
 CLASS lcl_util IMPLEMENTATION.
   METHOD write_struct.
     FIELD-SYMBOLS:
     <field> TYPE any.
     WRITE / '('.
     DO.
       ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF STRUCTURE p_struct TO <field>.
       IF sy-subrc <> 0.
         EXIT.
       ENDIF.
       WRITE /4 <field>.
     ENDDO.
     WRITE / ')'.
   ENDMETHOD.                    "write_struct
 ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_util IMPLEMENTATION

 DATA:
 data_ref TYPE REF TO data,
 where_tab LIKE TABLE OF p_where.

FIELD-SYMBOLS:
 <line> TYPE any.

 START-OF-SELECTION.

   CREATE DATA data_ref TYPE (p_from).
   ASSIGN data_ref->* TO <line>.
*   APPEND p_where TO where_tab.

  SELECT * FROM (p_from) INTO <line> WHERE (p_where).

     CALL METHOD lcl_util=>write_struct
       EXPORTING
         p_struct = <line>.

   ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: Your `p_where` parameter restricts the selection. Can you check how many entries you have in your table with this restriction?

Comment: It's definitely the condition. For me your code runs just fine: exactly as many times, as rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

That SELECT-ENDSELECT structure is dependent on the selection criteria, so if there is no match, the call to the class is skipped or it will only execute based on how many rows are returned. 
From the structure of the logic, at execution time, its hard to know how many times the loop will execute. 
Typically, SELECT-ENDSELECT structures should be avoided as they can affect performance and in this case make it difficult knowing how many rows matched the selection criteria.
My suggestion would be to: (1) Select the entries into an internal table. (2) Then loop on that internal table, calling your method to write the table entries out.

Here is a good [blog post](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Community/ABAP+Performance+tips) regarding performance tips.
Here is a good [blog post](http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/testing-and-troubleshooting/blog/2012/09/21/selectinto-table-faster-than-selectendselect-the-real-reason) regarding SELECT INTO vs. SELECT-ENDSELECT